# In stripe invoices quantity is not showing properly

Tags: stripe-payments, strip, invoice

I have used stripe payment method to do my order management. So when ever i ordered and paid a invoice will be created. My amount to be paid is coming correcly, but quantity is showing wrong.`your text`

this is the code i have used for creating invoices

```
 `  if (createinvoice) {
      if (lineItems && lineItems.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; lineItems.length > i; i++) {
          var element = lineItems[i];
          await stripe.invoiceItems.create({
            customer: customerid,
       `     amount:
              parseFloat((element.Price * 100).toFixed(2)) * element.Quantity,
            currency: "sgd",
            description: element.ItemName,
            metadata: { ConversationID: convID, RowKey: rowkey },
          });
        }
      }
      const invoiceitem = await stripe.invoices.create({
        customer: customerid,
      });
      invoice_id = invoiceitem.id;
      const invoice = await stripe.invoices.finalizeInvoice(invoice_id);
    }
   
    const invoice1 = await stripe.invoices.retrieve(invoice_id);
    const shortenedURL = invoice1.hosted_invoice_url;
    return shortenedURL;
  }``
```

Tried this code to create invoice, I'm expecting a invoice with proper quantity printing

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed a [quantity](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create#create_invoiceitem-quantity) param, so it's defaulting to 1.

your code should look something like

```
await stripe.invoiceItems.create({
  customer: customerid,
  unit_amount: parseInt(element.Price * 100, 10),
  quantity: element.Quantity,
  currency: "sgd",
  description: element.ItemName,
  metadata: { 
    ConversationID: convID, RowKey: rowkey 
  },
});
```

EDIT:

Since Stripe version [2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01), the default behavior of Pending Invoice Items has changed. So now you need to specify `pending_invoice_items_behavior: 'include'` when you create the invoice.

```
 const invoiceitem = await stripe.invoices.create({
   customer: customerid,
   pending_invoice_items_behavior: 'include'
 });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to add like this but I'm getting error. DialogContextError: You may only specify one of these parameters: amount, quantity.
    at D:\CycleMart-demo-V2\node_modules\botbuilder-dialogs\lib\dialogContext.js:40:19
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)

Comment: Yes my bad, it's unit_amount not amount.

Comment: Hi,  i tried the code, but when ever a payment link is generated it is  showing paid and amount is zero.

Comment: I think the problem is with the invoice creation you need to specify the `pending_invoice_items_behavior: 'include'`. I updated the main answer for this

Comment: Got this error  :DialogContextError: Received unknown parameter: pending_invoice_items_behavior
    at D:\CycleMart-demo-V2\node_modules\botbuilder-dialogs\lib\dialogContext.js:40:19
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (D:\CycleMart-demo-V2\node_modules\botbuilder-dialogs\lib\dialogContext.js:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {

Comment: which version of stripe-node have you installed?

Comment: version is 11.11.0

Comment: where did you add the `pending_invoice_items_behavior` param?